# How can I display an image on top of an image in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am creating a version of Pong in Python 3, using the library PyGame. I am trying to render an image as the "table" background, then displaying the 
ball on top of it. My issue is that the ball is the only image showing, displaying a black background. However, if I remove the code pertaining to the ball, the "table" image shows. How may I render the ball on top of the table?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = [500,500]
speed = [2,2]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


table = pygame.image.load('table.jpg')
table_rect = table.get_rect()



paddle_one = table = pygame.image.load('paddle.jpg')
paddle_one_rect = paddle_one.get_rect()





while True:

    screen.blit(table, table_rect)

    screen.blit(paddle_one, paddle_one_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion **the problem is that you overwrite your `table` `pygame.Surface` instance** by calling

```
paddle_one = table = pygame.image.load('paddle.jpg')
```

Try to **remove the second assignment**

```
paddle_one = pygame.image.load('paddle.jpg')
```

Now **both Surfaces** `table` und `paddle_one` **store *different* images** und can be blitted onto another surface (e.g. the `screen`) using Pygames [`.blit()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @elegant Thank you so much. I honestly did not even notice the: paddle_one = table = pygame.image.load('paddle.jpg') .... silly bugs. Thank you.